# Как для textView установить стиль нажатия и картинку?

Tags: android, textview

Для textView установил картинку с помощью android:background="", но стиль нажатия устанавливается также через этот тег, как можно решить такую проблему?

Comment: что за "стиль нажатия"? опишите ваш вопрос более конкретно. Варианты есть, но не знаю, что вы хотите получить в итоге

Comment: Там анимация, например волны, есть стандартная схема для отображения, находится по пути ?attr/selected....и т.д.

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите добиться в итоге. Сделайте `FrameLayout`, вставьте в него первым виджетом `ImageView` с нужной картинкой (как в бэке), а вторым - `TextView` с нужным вам эффектом.

Comment: @Jarvis_J, никак не могу понять, почему вы не понимаете, вроде бы разъяснил все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для совмещения различных изображений и свойств используем layer-list. Где каждый item - это отдельный слой, на котором располагается изображение или эффект.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_crop_square_black_24dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Эффект при нажатии, допустим разбегающийся круг задается shape. Здесь задаем его тип и поведение. Так же цвет, радиус и прочее..

```
   <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient android:type="radial"
            android:gradientRadius="100dp"
            android:startColor="#00ffffff"
            android:endColor="#adffffff"/>
    </shape>
```

Его можно добавить в lasyer-list как item.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_crop_square_black_24dp"/>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <gradient
            android:type="radial"
            android:gradientRadius="100%p"
            android:startColor="#00ffffff"
            android:endColor="#ad562121">
        </gradient>
    </shape>
</item>
```

И переключатель состояний(нажатие, фокус, переключение и т. д.) selector и animated-selector.

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer" android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Где опять же, каждый item - может быть как изображением или shape, так и layer-list. Так же в нем определяется состояние, для которого этот item характерен. Это все создается как xml файл в папке drawable. Создавать их можно как отдельных файлах ,так и в одном.